# Why is the time of useful consciousness only seconds at high altitudes, when I can hold my breath much longer at ground level?

Tags: emergency, hypoxia, physiological

[This answer says](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44748/how-long-does-it-take-for-pilots-to-become-unconscious-after-an-uncontrolled-dep) at FL500 (50,000 ft; 15,250 m) the time of useful consciousness is only 6 to 9 seconds.

But if I just stop breathing at any arbitrary time, without any preparation, I can easily continue without air for about 20 seconds. How can these times be so short?

Comment: It's worth noting that the time of "useful consciousness" is much shorter than the time of "consciousness", because the effects that appear in the situation make the consciousness much less useful to solve practical problems: Tunnel vision and euphoria may be very distracting, while still being conscious.

Comment: I the graphics and details in [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/77852/66173) answer - when you are fully exhaled at sea level, you have more leftover air in your lungs than you have when you are fully inhaled up at that altitude.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

When you are breathing, oxygen ($\mathrm{O}_2$) and carbon dioxide ($\mathrm{CO}_2$) are exchanged between the alveoli in your lungs and the environment. This gas exchange is based on [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion), which means the partial pressures of each gas involved will move towards equalization:

> Henry’s law states that the amount of a specific gas that dissolves in a liquid is a function of its partial pressure. The greater the partial pressure of a gas, the more of that gas will dissolve in a liquid, as the gas moves toward equilibrium.

([source](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-ap2/chapter/gas-exchange/))

As long as the oxygen partial pressure is higher in the environment, your blood will gain oxygen from breathing. But if the oxygen partial pressure is lower, you lose oxygen from breathing. Therefore, holding your breath at sea level gives you more time until you run out of oxygen than breathing at 15km altitude, where total pressure is about 10 times lower than at sea level. Furthermore, as John K pointed out in the comments, holding your breath at sea level allows you to *feel* when you need to breathe again, because of increasing $\mathrm{CO}_2$ levels, where breathing at high altitude does not feel different because $\mathrm{CO}_2$ can still leave your system.

This principle also allows [oxygen masks in aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergency_oxygen_system) to function without creating higher pressure. Since (more or less) pure oxygen is created, the oxygen partial pressure is much higher than in the surrounding air despite being at the same total pressure.

Comment: So if you could hold your breath, you could stay conscious for a minute or so as normal, but attempting to breath no only removes the remaining oxygen from your lungs, but also removes oxygen from your blood?

Comment: @RobinBennett In principle yes. But note that during a rapid depressurization you cannot really *hold your breath*. The air will be forced out of your lungs anyway. Holding your breath at sea level pressure gives you the "minute or so". I clarified the answer.

Comment: Other thing is that when holding your breath on the ground what forces you to breath again is the carbon dioxide buildup in your blood, not the lack of oxygen. If it wasn't for that, you could easily make yourself pass out. When cabin pressure is reduced slowly, you won't even be aware of the pressure drop because you are still able to expel CO2. When I took a High Altitude Indoctrination chamber ride back in the 80s, the biggest surprise when I started breathing 25000 ft ambient air was I couldn't tell the difference, just sitting still in my chamber seat, until the hypoxia symptoms set in.

Comment: @JohnK Good point, I added it to the answer.

Comment: We recently had a question about an [ATC controller suffering from a stroke](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/69811/18733) while on duty. Some of the commenters to the [original YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jv1kmuFOhWk) said they had a stroke themselves and didn't notice either. I suppose it is the same with that low-oxygen situation: You just don't notice yourself and that makes it so dangerous.

Comment: @JohnK's point about CO2 levels being important [is also relevant at sea level or even below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freediving_blackout). There's quite a lot of information about this reflex as purging the body of CO2 is a cause of drowning in freediving

Comment: @PerlDuck the biggest problem is that for many people the initial hypoxia symptom is the euphoria stage, which is very similar to being on laughing gas at the dentist.  My initial symptom, luckily for me, was tunnel vision. Meanwhile a seatmate went straight to euphoria and was cackling in laughter as he tried to draw his shapes.  I reconnected when I felt a weird dunk sensation well up as I observed my tunnel vision, then all the symptoms vanished.  You're sitting drawing characters on a clip board. As your characters become all lop sided, you are AWARE that they are lopsided, but don't care.

Comment: @RobinBennett correct, but (as you may know but isn't pointed out in the answer yet) you *can't* hold your breath through a decompression event even if you know it's coming. It's not possible to sustain a significant pressure differential between the inside of your lungs and the cabin. The air will get out, probably doing some damage along the way if you try to keep your nose and mouth shut.

Comment: This is essentially the same reason [why hyperventilating before diving is so dangerous](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1114047/): it reduces your CO2 without affecting O2, so it suppresses your need to breathe, potentially until it's too late.

Comment: @RobinBennett : The problem is that when the pressure drops, your body won't shut down your breathing automatically. There is no reason to, because our ancestors never encountered such problems. By the time you consciously realize what happened, you already breathed out the precious contents of your lungs. On the other hand, if you fall into water, your body stops the breathing automatically and instantly (as our ancestors often faced such situations).

Comment: @Bianfable Yes you can, and it's ***lethal***. In scuba diving, there's a standard technique called CESA (controlled emergency swimming ascent) where if your air fails and your buddy mysteriously vanishes, you swim up to the surface. You're trained to do a controlled exhale throughout the ascent, because if you hold your breath then the gas expands as the water pressure reduces, and it can fatally rupture your lungs.

Comment: @JohnK: you can cause yourself to pass out from lack of O2 if you hyperventilate first, because it lowers your blood CO2, and it can be very dangerous: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freediving_blackout#Shallow_water_blackout

Answer (score 24):

The situation in a high altitude depressurization is different because:

1. The air in your lungs is now "FL500 air" - i.e. the pressure is about 0.1 atmosphere. This means that the partial pressure of O<sub>2</sub> (ppO<sub>2</sub>) is about 0.021 atm, instead of 0.21 atm. Oxygen will rapidly diffuse out of your blood and into your lungs, and your brain will very soon not have enough oxygen to function. (You can actually manage with a slightly lower partial pressure of O<sub>2</sub> - scuba diving mixes are often considered "hypoxic" once they're below 16% O<sub>2</sub>, since your can breath a ppO<sub>2</sub> of 0.16 atm and function normally. But note that this is 8 times greater than 0.02 atm).
2. You cannot hold your last breath of cabin pressure air. To try do so would in fact be very dangerous, since your lungs would be trying to support a 0.9 atm pressure difference between the inside and outside. Scuba divers are taught to never hold their breath while ascending for exactly this reason - the pressure difference can rupture the alveoli in your the lung. This can result in gas passing directly into the blood and causing an embolism.
3. But if you stick on an oxygen mask, that 0.1 atm of air (with a ppO<sub>2</sub> of 0.02) has been replaced by 0.1 atm of O<sub>2</sub>. So your ppO<sub>2</sub> is then 0.1. Still not ideal, but much better than 0.02 atm.

Comment: If you're wearing an oxygen mask at FL500, it's going to be a pressure-demand mask (which feeds oxygen to your lungs at higher-than-ambient pressure), providing your lungs with a ppO2 of 0.16-0.2 atm (this leaves your lungs holding a small pressure differential - 0.06-0.1 atm in our example, potentially up to 0.18-0.2 atm at higher altitudes - but they handle small pressure differentials like these without much trouble).

Comment: 0.16atm ppO2 allows functioning normally if you're not exerting too much.  You'll probably feel it if you try to run up a flight of stairs, or cycle over mountain passes (I've done both at around that pressure)

Comment: Ok so the idea is that the pressure in the bloodstream is controlled by the external air or water pressure, while the pressure of the gas in the alveoli can be raised well above the external air or water pressure by holding one's breath during decompression or rapid ascent--

Comment: At FL500 your mask doesn't work very well.

Comment: @quietflyer I don't think I'd use the phrasing "well above" in that context.  Alveoli start to rupture and create air emboli at very little above 0.2 atm, and it takes conscious effort to exhale at much lower pressure difference than that -- making just breathing a tiring task over a fairly short term.  Most people cannot exhale at all against 0.2 atm.

Answer (score 4):

It's also the starting gun.

When you hold your breath, you choose when to start.  That is known.

In a hypoxia incident, you rarely discover the pressurization problem at the very start of the event. It may be well along before you notice it.   So you don't know when you actually started "holding your breath".

It would be more of a fair comparison if the failing system went "loss of cabin pressure in 3, 2, 1...” But of course, it doesn't do that!

Comment: There's explosive decompression and nonexplosive decompression.